# Person Segmentation on iPhone XR with ARKit 3.0

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, occlusion, iphone-xr

The following piece of code returns false on iPhone XR even-though it person segmentation is working on XR.

```
ARConfiguration.supportsFrameSemantics(.personSegmentation)
```

I want to know if it does officially supports person segmentation and person segmentation with depth on XR. Just to point out I have got iOS 13.1.2 on the XR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this variation:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let config = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()

    if ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.supportsFrameSemantics(.personSegmentationWithDepth) {
        config.frameSemantics = .personSegmentationWithDepth
    }
    arView.session.run(config)
}
```

And make sure that your ***Xcode version is 11.2.1*** and ***iOS version is 13.2.3***.

Comment: I was using **ARConfiguration** for checking the support. I needed to use **ARWorldTrackingConfiguration** to check the support.

Comment: `ARConfiguration` is a base class for all types of configurations in ARKit, but `ARWorldTrackingConfiguration` is a main one with six degrees of freedom.